# Split variable using a special character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable `var i = "my*text"` I want to split it using special character `*`. I mean, I want to generate `var one` = "my" and `var two` = "text" from the above variable.

How can I do this using jQuery and (or) JavaScript?
.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
values=i.split('*');
one=values[0];
two=values[1];
```

Comment: this is applicable if variable has only one spl char.. How if it contain multiple chars and i want to obtain all possible pieces??

Comment: @blasteralfred: This will split string where ever the `*` is encountered and return an array containing all the pieces. In above case `values` is an array containing all the pieces you need.

Answer (score 5):

use     `string.split(separator, limit)`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str="my*text";
str.split("*");
</script>
```

Comment: How if it contain multiple chars and i want to obtain all possible pieces??

Answer (score 3):

Just to add, the comma operator is your friend here:

```
var i = "my*text".split("*"), j = i[0], k = i[1];
alert(j + ' ' + k);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EKB5g/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` method:

```
var result = i.split('*');
```

The variable result now contains an array with two items:

```
result[0] : 'my'
result[1] : 'text'
```

You can also use string operations to locate the special character and get the strings before and after that:

```
var index = i.indexOf('*');
var one = i.substr(0, index);
var two = i.substr(index + 1, i.length - index - 1);
```